# How to update page views in batches, not every time page loads

Tags: mysql, memcached, optimization

We have a high load site that has a forum which has been programmed to increment topic pageview every time that topic page loads. In peak hours these writes become a bottleneck and MySQL gets locked up. Is there a way to keep pageviews in memory and then update once in at an interval (e.g. every minute) in a single query?

Our stack is: Ruby on Rails 2.3.8, MySQL 5.1, Memcached, Nginx + Passenger

**UPDATE:** In other words, instead of 20,000 single updates for 500 threads over 1 minute, I want to make only 500 updates every 1 minute, 1 update per thread.

Comment: Maybe limit the actual write function to once per session per user. This takes the writes out of refreshes and frequent revisits to the same page in a short period of time.

Comment: This question may relate to info that we MUST save but not as often, so limiting like this is not a solution for other similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

Look at MongoDB. Write operations are quite fast. No need to change anything in your mysql

You can create one collection with your postids &  increment counts accordingly.

upsert and $inc operators.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Deployments

Comment: How big of a performance advantage would it give over MySQL updates?

Comment: See it depends on your data-set & application requirement. Best approach will be if you give it a try instead of relying on any stats.I used it on high load site for delivering pageviews on each page load & found it quite fast for write as well as reads.

Answer (score 0):

If you're leaving this up to Rails, the logic is probably a select, then math, then an insert, like so:

```
@foo = SELECT view_count FROM pages WHERE ID = '1';

@bar = @foo + 1

UPDATE pages SET view_count = @bar WHERE ID = '1';
```

For lack of a better way to put it.

However, MySQL can handle this guy by himself.

In Rails:

```
records = update_sql('UPDATE pages SET view_count = view_count + 1 WHERE ID = #{@baz.id}')
```

"records" will be the number of rows affected, and can be used to see if it worked

```
flash[:error] = "Fail!" if !records
```

Comment: THis results in one query instead of two and minimal data transfer between the database and the application

Comment: Problem is it's still too many queries (even if you do only one) for a trivial and not so important thing as thread viewcounts. These updates take processing power from more important queries, and that's why instead of 20,000 single updates for 500 threads over 1 minute, I want to make only 500 updates every 1 minute.

Comment: By that logic, wouldn't you indefinitely form a queue of updates waiting to be processed? If these are your actual stats and desired result, that's 40 batch updates created per minute and only one per minute being processed. In a high traffic time of ten minutes, you'd be set back 390 batch updates to be processed for the next 5.5 hours. I think you may need to re-evaluate what you're looking for and see if there are other places you can optimize.

Comment: No, what I am thinking is if we could keep pageviews in RAM (e.g. Memcached) and not increment in queries like UPDATE forum_topics SET pageviews = pageviews + 1, but in batches like UPDATE forum_topics SET pageviews = pageviews + 45, which would just run less often.